# Would this routine work?

Tags: strength, strength-training, routine

> EDIT: I have edited it to add in based on the helpful advice given in the answer by user **meanderingmoose**

I have been doing weightlifting for a while now, staying mainly to well know routines(stronglifts->madcows, greyskull LP, 5/3/1)

---

Basic information(Possibly relevant):

Height 6ft

Weight 77kg

Bench 1RM 105kg

Deadlift 1RM 150kg

Squat 150kg(330lb)

Barbell rows 1RM 80kg

OHP 1RM 70kg

---

I am not making progress on any normal routines anymore, even though I am eating 500 calories excess a day now.

The routine I wanted to try I made up on the spot by taking all main lifts, and putting them in an order that stops them from impacting one another.

(Not including warm up single set)

---

---

Day 1: Clean and press 5x5 Deadlift 1x5

Day off

Day 3: Barbell rows 5x5,Bench 5x5

Day 4: Overhead 5x5

Day 5: Squats 5x5

Day 6: Bench 5x5, Barbell rows 5x5

Day off
Repeat

So they are all done with no gap except for the repeat.

So would this work?

Comment: Your deadlift jumps out at me as quite low compared to your other lifts, which are solid. Is there a particular reason for that? What's caused you to stop making progress? Do  you mean progress in lift numbers, your own mass, or hypertrophy?

Comment: Your proposed routine is similar in some ways to 5/3/1, maybe reading up on that could help.

Comment: @DaveLiepmann Yeah my hands can't seem to handle deadlifting any higher, not really sure why, even with alternate grip(and I can't get over 95kg with hook).

Yeah progress on all lifts(weight) has stalled, other than possibly overhead press.

I will go have a look at 5/3/1 now. I think I may have heard of it before.

Comment: @DaveLiepmann yes actually, I have tried out 5/3/1, but it felt so inactive I couldn't stick to it(despite the fact that it likely would have worked). For some reason find myself demotivated in general on non-workout days I have found, so I was wanted something daily, but I know splits don't really work, so I was considering daily compounds that don't conflict.

Comment: I recommend chalk for deadlifts if you haven't tried that yet. Makes an immense difference.

Comment: @DaveLiepmann I have heard that it helps, I will have to buy some soon. Do you have any other recommendations in regards to the deadlift? Perhaps one warm up set of 5 is bad, or 1x5 isn't a good rep count?

Comment: A good workout requires good nutrition.  Show your support for nutrition.SE here:  http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/44550/nutrition

Comment: @Mew it almost looks from your account activity that you are spamming that :\.

Comment: @DisplayName, perhaps but it is for a good cause.  I don't gain anything personally from it, I just think this site will be very helpful to society if it gets up and running.

Comment: 1x5 on the DL is usually fine until you're near 2xBW. But...wait a second, only one warm-up set? You warm up your 150kg squats with only one set? Usually people spend several sets warming up, like: 1x5 of 20kg, 60kg, 100kg, 120kg, then 150kg 5x5. You should get a form check on every lift, too, while you're at it.

Comment: @DaveLiepmann I usually just do a warm up for squats at 95kg and then straight to working weight, I feel like mostly warm ups are for mental state, and they wear me down by the time I get to my working set. Should I decrease my working set so I can do both, and perhaps it will break me through plateau?

Comment: @Mew Okay, I will upvote some in that case.

Comment: If you can't handle a few warm-up sets then you need to work on your work capacity. Three sets of 5 at submaximal weights shouldn't really give you trouble. Those sets are A) good practice and B) a way to accumulate volume. I don't know if you should drop your work weights in order to fit your warm-ups, but if you have to, then you have to.

Comment: @DaveLiepmann Okay. Thank you for all your comments and/or help! Greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Allowing the lifts to impact each other does not necessarily mean decreased productivity. You mentioned that you have stalled in your lifts; reducing the number of times you perform a certain lift to 1 will make it difficult to get out of this stall. With a caloric surplus like you mentioned, you have the ability to recover enough to perform each lift 2+ times a week. This means you will need to do multiple main lifts a day, which means you will need to pick one to do first while you're fresh. The others will be done while fatigued which, while it may decrease your numbers for the day, will help you to increase them over time.

For example, barbell rows and bench press are two of your body lifts here, so instead of having separate days for them, lets do both exercises on both Day 3 and Day 6. The benefit here is that on Day 3, you can row fresh then bench while tired, and on Day 6 do the opposite. You will still hit the same initial workout you would have on your program, but now you have the added benefit of a second piece of work. As you work at it, you will see the weights you can lift in the fatigued workouts increase, and as these numbers go up, your numbers for lifting fresh will increase as well.

For the more intensive lifts in your program, deadlifts and squats, I would be careful with doing both in one day. You can (especially if you decide to keep deadlift at 1x5), but if you feel your body tell you no, don't force it. Especially when trying to do deadlifts after squatting, I sometimes can tell I have nothing, and find myself struggling at <50% of my max. At this point you can recognize that you had an excellent initial workout and avoid potential injury with an additional main set.

Comment: Thank you for this, I will try it out and update here with the results.